# Regex "AND" in an expression extract this and that

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to write a regex that extracts the following numbers in bold below.
I set up 3 different regex for each value, but since the last value might have a space in between I don't know how to accommodate an "AND" here.

tire = 'Tire: P**275**/**65**R**18** A/S; **275**/**65**R **18** A/T OWL;**265**/**70**R **17** A/T OWL;'

I have tried this and it is working for the first 2 but not for the last one.  I'd like to have the last one in a single regex.

```
p1 = re.compile(r'(\d+)/')
p2 = re.compile(r'/(\d+)')
p3 = re.compile(r'(?=.*[R](\d+))(?=.*[R]\s(\d+))')
```

I've tried different stuff and this is the last code I tried with unsuccessful results

if I do this

```
p1.findall(tire), p2.findall(tire), p3.findall(tire)
```

I would like to see this:

```
(['275', '275', '265'], ['65', '65', '70'], ['18', '18', '17'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! You don't need three separate regular expressions.
Instead, use multiple capturing groups in a single regex.

`(\d{3})\/(\d{2})R\s?(\d{2})`

Try it: https://regex101.com/r/Xn6bry/1

Explanation:

- `(\d{3})`: Capture three digits
- `\/`: Match a forward-slash
- `(\d{2})`: Capture two digits
- `R\s?`: Match an `R` followed by an optional whitespace
- `(\d{2})`: Capture two digits.

In Python, do:

```
p1 = re.compile(r'(\d{3})\/(\d{2})R\s?(\d{2})')
tire = 'Tire: P275/65R18 A/S; 275/65R 18 A/T OWL;265/70R 17 A/T OWL;'
matches = re.findall(p1, tire)
```

Now if you look at `matches`, you get
`[('275', '65', '18'), ('275', '65', '18'), ('265', '70', '17')]`

Rearranging this to the format you want should be pretty straightforward:

```
# Make an empty list-of-list with three entries - one per group
groups = [[], [], []]
for match in matches:
    for groupnum, item in enumerate(match):
        groups[groupnum].append(item)
```

Now `groups` is `[['275', '275', '265'], ['65', '65', '70'], ['18', '18', '17']]`